# replace . with a ~

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string `'abc.132131.001.3'` . I want to replace each occurrence of `'.'` with `'~'`.

I have used

```
str.replace(/[.*?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\~$&");
```

but the output for this is

```
abc~.132131~.001~.3
```

I also tried

```
str.replace(/./g, "~");
```

and this returns

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the second argument to `replace`, which you have `"\~$&"`.

The backreference `$&` backreferences the entire matched string. In this case, `.` is the matched string. So you are replacing `.` with `~` followed by the matched `.`.

Remove `$&` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

> *I have used `str.replace(/[.*?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\~$&");` but the output for this is `abc~.132131~.001~.3`.*

That regular expression matches any of the characters in the outer `[]` brackets, *not just full stops*, but in your replacement string the `$&` part has the special meaning of whatever text the regex matched, which would be the full stop `.` character. So you are changing each `.` to `~.`. You could just update your replacement string to `"~"` and you'd get the output you want.

> *I also tried `str.replace(/./g, "~");` and this returns `'~~~~~~~~~~~~'`.*

That's because in a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters) a `.` that is not inside a "character set" with square brackets (as in your other attempt) matches any character except newline characters, so every character in your string gets replaced.

To search for a literal full-stop `'.'` character you have to escape it in the regex by using a backslash:

```js
 var str = 'abc.132131.001.3'
 
 var result = str.replace(/\./g, '~')
 
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: `/[.]/` also matches the literal `.`, which is in the question.

Comment: @JoeFrambach - True. To be honest I didn't read the first attempt very carefully because of the way it was formatted before you fixed it. I can add something about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [`join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp).

```js
var string = "abc.132131.001.3";
document.write(string.split(".").join("~"));
```